# Determine Node Touched in Gesture Recognizer

Tags: sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a SpriteKit scene that can have thousands of distinct nodes in it.  I am also implementing a single-tap gesture recognizer on the scene, in the hopes that I can determine which node has been touched in the scene once the gesture recognizer is triggered.  Currently, my (non-working) code looks like this:

```
@objc func singleTap(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    print("single tap gesture recognized")

    if sender.numberOfTouches == 1 {

        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.view)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchPoint)

        if let name = touchedNode.name
        {
            if name == "newMapButton"
            {
                print("newMapButton Touched")
            } else {
                print("what did you touch?")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The gesture recognizer is working.  When I touch the new map button I get the "single tap gesture recognized" in the console, but nothing more. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your `touchedNode.name` doesnt exist

Comment: also, you are getting your touchPoint in `View` coordinates, not `Scene` coordinates

Comment: if your scene class is your delegate for gestures, then add `let sceneTouchPoint = convertPoint(fromView:touchPoint)`   If your view controller is your delegate, then add `if let skView = view as! SKView{let sceneTouchPoint = skView.convert(touchPoint,to:skView.scene) ...(Rest of code)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In GameScene file, I created my button in didMove method like so

   ```
   let btnTest = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button")
   btnTest.setScale(0.2)
   btnTest.name = "Button"
   btnTest.zPosition = 10
   btnTest.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200)
   self.addChild(btnTest)
   ```
2. Adding Gesture in didMove:

   ```
   let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()
   tapRec.addTarget(self, action:#selector(GameScene.tappedView(_:) ))
   tapRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
   tapRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
   self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
   ```
3. Finally implementing tappedView method

   ```
   @objc func tappedView(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   if sender.state == .ended {

       var post = sender.location(in: sender.view)
       post = self.convertPoint(fromView: post)
       let touchNode = self.atPoint(post)

       if let name = touchNode.name
       {
           if name == "Button"
           {
               print("newMapButton Touched")
           } else {
               print("what did you touch?")
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Your code should fail,  View coordinates and Scene Coordinates differ.

Comment: i used co-ordinate for testing, main goal was to detect touch. Didn't you get the touch?

Comment: poster said he was able to get the touch, he couldn't get the node

Comment: did you run my code? I have got the node, if i didn't why should I bother to post an answer?

Comment: I don't need to run your code,  I know it doesn't work as intended.  Maybe you got lucky because you placed a button the size of the entire scene into your code, or you placed a button in the middle of the scene, and set the scene size the same as the view size and the anchor point at (0,0), but your code is going to fail in other situations.  View's default coordinate system has (0,0) being top left,  scene default has (0,0) in the center.  If I placed a button at (0,0) and touched the middle `sender.location(in:self.view)` returns view.width/2,view.height/2, missing the button

Comment: thank you for clarifying my mistake. But I didn't use entire scene as a button. I will check your solution in other scenarios.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, I have edited my answer and test the Node in different position. Is it OK now? or anything I am missing? please let me know

Comment: Yes, it should be.  I see touch -> view -> scene conversion happening now