# Not able to select pause button I have added to the screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touchesbegan

My game is setup with a background, a road in the middle of it, then a bar at the top which displays the score and pause button. zPositon of the road and background are 1. The bar at the top zPosition is 4, and the pause button zPosition is 4 as well.

Code for road and background.

```
    road.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0))
    road.zPosition = 1
    road.name = roadName
    background.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0))
    background.zPosition = 1
    background.name = backgroundName

    addChild(background)
    addChild(road)
```

Code for the bar at the top.

```
    topBar = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: CGFloat(150)))
    topBar.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: (screenHeight/2) + topBar.size.height/2)
    topBar.zPosition = 4
    topBar.name = topBarName

    addChild(topBar)
```

Code for the pause button.

```
    pauseButton.position = CGPoint(x: (-topBar.size.width/2) + (pauseButton.size.width + (pauseButton.size.width/2)), y: 0)
    pauseButton.zPosition = 4
    pauseButton.name = pauseButtonName

    topBar.addChild(pauseButton)
```

In my touches began function, I attempted to search for the nodes at the position of the touch, but it only returns the names of the road and background. It doesn't even pick up the topBar or pause button.

```
for node in nodes
            {
                print(node.name)

                if node.name == pauseButtonName
                {
                    print("paused")
                }
            }
```

This will output

```
Optional("Road")
Optional("Background")
```

I also tried this method, but "paused" was never returned.

```
 if pauseButton.contains(touch.location(in: self))
            {
                print("paused")
            }
```

I think it may be important to note that the top bar is positioned off the screen initially. When you start the game, it runs an SKAction to move the bar on screen.

```
topBar.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: (screenHeight/2) - (topBar.size.height/2), duration: 0.5))
```

Why am I not able to select the pause button, and how can this be resolved?

Comment: did you [try this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328886/detect-touch-on-child-node-of-object-in-spritekit)?

Comment: you are adding the topBar to the SKScene and detecting the touch in View. You need to convert the location to SKScene to SKView location. [Read this question and comments of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358366/determine-node-touched-in-gesture-recognizer/50359364#50359364). It may help

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using this code. Instead of checking for the location in the game scene, I checked for it in the topBar.

```
if pauseButton.contains(touch.location(in: topBar))
{
    print("paused")
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem right, touching anywhere in the topBar would cause it to pass/pause

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That is not the case. I have tested it on my app, and also added another button to the topBar which works as well. It's checks if the point at which I touched the screen exist within the pause buttons coordinate system. Since the pause button is only in the top left corner, it only gets called when I press in that location.